# Test-Path false for UNC path

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to get `Get-Acl` to work but it seems that when I use UNC path, it returns false. I ran `Test-Path` and it also returns false.

I tested `Test-Path` on my local folders and still the same. UNC path returns false but when normal path it returns true. What am I doing wrong?

```
PS C:\windows\system32> Get-Acl \\computername\Asset
Get-Acl : Cannot find path '\\phmangang01\Asset' because it does not exist.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-Acl \\phmangang01\Asset
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (:) [Get-Acl], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetAcl_PathNotFound_Exception,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetAclCommand

PS C:\windows\system32> Get-Acl C:\Asset

    Directory: C:\

Path  Owner                  Access
----  -----                  ------
Asset BUILTIN\Administrators BUILTIN\Administrators Allow  FullControl...

PS C:\windows\system32> Test-Path \\computer name\Asset
False
PS C:\windows\system32> Test-Path C:\Asset
True
```

Comment: You are missing a backslash `\ `  > should be `test-path \\ComputerName\C$`

Comment: sorry, I've must deleted it while editing the computername
PS C:\windows\system32> Test-Path \\computername\Asset
False
PS C:\windows\system32> Test-Path C:\Asset
True

Comment: try to add the drive `test-path \\ComputerName\C$\Asset`

Comment: ohh now it is working. Why is that?
I tried it on a fileshare both returns false
PS C:\windows\system32> Test-Path \\server\C$\nartools
False
PS C:\windows\system32> Test-Path \\server\nartools
False

Comment: Has the folder been shared in the first place? What does `net share` on the server show?

Comment: I dont have access to the server, Im just testing it  as they are asking for a script. The folders are home drive of users. So if folder is not shared with me it will return false?

Comment: Perhaps surprisingly, accessing a network share (`\\computer\share` or `\\computer\share\sub\folder`) requires the shared folder to actually be shared.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any shares on your target machine, your have to add the drive in the unc path. But if so you further have to mask the $-symbol with a tick mark, because it's a special regex-character:
"\\ComputerName\C`$\Asset"